# Making a single row of a 3x3 data.frame

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame

```
  example.df <- data.frame(target.condition = c("congruent", "incongruent", "neutral"),
                       sdGY.2 = sample(20:30, 3, replace = T),
                       sdGX.2 = sample(20:30, 3, replace = T))
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
 congruent.sdGY.2 congruent.sdGX.2 incongruent.sdGY.2 incongruent.sdGX.2 neutral.sdGY.2 neutral.sdGX.2
1               28               29                 20                 23             27             29
```

I did this by using:

```
  test <- data.frame(congruent.sdGY.2 = example.df$sdGY.2[1], congruent.sdGX.2 = example.df$sdGX.2[1],
                 incongruent.sdGY.2 = example.df$sdGY.2[2], incongruent.sdGX.2 = example.df$sdGX.2[2],
                 neutral.sdGY.2 = example.df$sdGY.2[3], neutral.sdGX.2 = example.df$sdGX.2[3])
```

I guess there is a easier method, right?

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages from the tidyverse.  This first changes the structure so both the sdGX.2 and sdGY.2 are in the same column in different rows, and then combines the column names together and then changes the structure so it has many columns.

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

 example.df %>% 
   gather(ColName, ResultValue, -target.condition) %>% 
   unite(NewColName, c("target.condition", "ColName"), sep = ".", remove = TRUE) %>% 
   spread(NewColName, ResultValue)
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect. I was trying to work with gather and spread, but didn't understand how it exactly worked. Can you explain what the -target.condition does, i cant find it in help. @Kerry Jackson

Comment: @BartR: Note that `example.df %>% gather(ColName, ResultValue, -target.condition)` is equivalent to `gather(example.df, ColName, ResultValue, -target.condition)`, so `-target.condition` is the forth argument. As you can see from the documentation, the fourth argument of `gather()` is ellipsis (`...`), and lets you select and deselect (by prepending with a `-`) columns.